# `UIApplicationDelegate` to `WKInterfaceController` data pass

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, watchkit

Any ideas on how to **pass this data** from my iOS **`AppDelegate.m`** to my WatchKit **`InterfaceController.m`**?

I run a `Parse` query in my iOS `AppDelegate.m`

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {
        NSString * request = [userInfo objectForKey:@"requestString"];
        if ([request isEqualToString:@"executeMethodA"]) {

            // GMT Date from Phone
            NSDate *gmtNow = [NSDate date];
            NSLog(@"GMT Now: %@", gmtNow);
            // Query Parse
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"na"];

            [query whereKey:@"dateGame" greaterThanOrEqualTo:gmtNow];

            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSMutableArray *localMatchup = [@[] mutableCopy];
                    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                        // Add objects to local Arrays
                        [localMatchup addObject:[object objectForKey:@"matchup"]];

                        // App Group
                        NSString *container = @"group.com.me.off";
                        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];

                        // Matchup
                        [defaults setObject:localMatchup forKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                        NSArray *savedMatchup = [defaults objectForKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                        NSLog(@"Default Matchup: %@", savedMatchup);

                 }


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"dispatch");
                });

                reply(@{@"localMatchup": localMatchup});
            }
            else {
                reply(@{@"error": error.description});
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Happy to post any extra code just ask, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `reply` block in your `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` method, run it with your data in a dict when you finish your query.

```
reply(@{@"localMatchup": localMatchup});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yeah I assumed I needed the `reply` block, but I didn't know since I was getting an `array` in the query how I was supposed to get it into a `dict` when I do the `reply` part.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just wrap it in a dictionary @{ "parseArray": arrayFromParse }

Comment: @SRMR Yeah, you can put it there. Additionally, I think it's better to also reply an error message when error happens.

Comment: Put that in a separate `reply` somewhere else, or do an NSLog?

Comment: @SRMR you already have a `!error if condition` just add an `else` to it, and reply something like this `reply(@{@"error": error.description})`.

Comment: Does the update in my code look right to you?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

i think you can call handleWatchKitExtensionRequest method

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I think thats the method I'm using tho already right?